# Set layer in edit mode in QGIS processing

Tags: qgis, python, layers, qgis-processing

Set a layer editable through the Python console works fine here (QGIS 2.18.4):

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
if not layer.isEditable():
    qgis.utils.iface.actionToggleEditing().trigger()
```

But I do not know how to set a input layer editable in a QGIS processing script:

```
##Input_layer=vector
# ...
inlayer = processing.getObject(Input_layer)
if not inlayer.isEditable():
    #???
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [QgsVectorLayer.startEditing()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1cb9fe1007c931a0e78195607ace518e).
Then once your edits are complete you can either [commitChanges()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#afab34baf331320a8c3212993f5fccfa1) or [rollBack()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a8b25c42160eff484340b7c413bda5414) as approriate

```
##Input_layer=vector
# ...
inlayer = processing.getObject(Input_layer)
if not inlayer.isEditable():
    inlayer.startEditing()
    # ...
    inlayer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: `inlayer.startEditing()` works fine, I just have to wait 22 hours to a award the bounty.