# Programmatically created and added vectorlayer can't be edited

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, editing, vector-layer

I'm trying to create a vector-layer (point, shapefile) and open it in my project. It all works fine but once I try to edit that layer later it doesn't work. addFeatures gives me back false and when I try to edit it via the Qgis Tools the adding Points is greyed out.
The odd part is, that I can open the layer I created via the Layer-Menu and it works fine. Also when I type in the code to open it in the console the layer is editable. But somehow in my plugin it doesn't work the same way.
This is the part of the code that should be relevant:

```
filename = self.dlg.lineEdit.text() # I get the directory from a lineEdit
dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)
path = dirname + '/name.shp'

project = QgsProject.instance()

fields=QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int))

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter( path, 'utf-8', fields, QgsWkbTypes.Point, project.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")

iface.addVectorLayer(path,"", "ogr")
```

Comment: maybe this helps? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231797/set-layer-in-edit-mode-in-qgis-processing

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can start editing without problems. But I can't add any features. In console the layer.addFeature(feature) gives back false. Using the Qgis Toolbar edit the add Points is greyed out. But it works when I open the same file in a different way

Comment: @Chris, what do you mean by this, "But it works when I open the same file in a different way"?

Comment: I can open the shapefile that was created with QgsVectorFileWriter useing the build-in Qgis Layer menu. If I open it "manually" and not from my plugin I can add features.

Comment: Also when I type in the iface.addVectorLayer(path,"", "ogr") into the console the layer works as intended. Only difference when i do it in the console is that i can't access the lineEdit and have to create the path seperatly. But I don't see where the path could be wrong as it is the same the file was created and it does open the correct layer i just can't add any features to it

Comment: Just did a little more testing and it really seems to be the paths fault. If I use in the addVectorLayer() instead the variable path a string of the form 'c:/some_directory/name.shp' the layer can be edited as usual. What is going wrong with my path I still don't know and why it still creates and opens the file with the path without a problem but doesn't let me add points to it I find a little odd. Would be great if someone could explain that to me#

Comment: One more Problem which actually belongs to the same Topic: I tried the same thing with a LineString now and the problem persists (the path problem I still don't know how to fix it) but while the point layer is editable when I give him a specific path the LineString is not (add line object button grey). Only thing I found so far to solve it is right click on the layer > save as > save the layer again and then I can edit it. But that is not practical at all it should work right away and I am clueless why it's not working.