# How to set a layer automatically in edit mode and addFeature mode

Tags: qgis-processing, editing, vector-layer

I have load a new layer in my QGIS project by a processing script. At the end I would like to set the layer in edit mode and addFeature mode. Thus the user only has to set the points afterwards.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
import processing

class LoadingData(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        pass

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': 'C:/Users/.../.../...gpkg',
            'NAME': 'Test'
        }
        outputs['LoadingData'] = processing.run('native:loadlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Loading'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Loading'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return LoadingData()
```

Comment: Check this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232125/99589

Comment: thanks that help for the edit mode